# Why does the copy constructor is not called?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, copy-constructor, default-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Init {
private:
    int x;
public:
    Init(int y) {
        x = y;
        cout << "default constructor called" << endl;
        
    }
    
    Init(std::shared_ptr<Init> z) {
        this->x = z->x;
        cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int k = 5;
    std::shared_ptr<Init> a = std::make_shared<Init>(k);
    std::shared_ptr<Init> b(a);

    return 0;
}
```

My expectation is to call both default and copy constructor, but only default constructor is called.
What might be the issue??

The output is:
**default construcor called**

Comment: `Init(std::shared_ptr<Init> z)` is not a copy constructor

Comment: Copy constructors must take a _reference_ parameter, not a pointer. See the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: @saxbophone It will be the `std::shared_ptr<Init>` copy constructor

Comment: There is only one `Init` instance; the one created by `make_shared`. I think you need to read some more about what `shared_ptr` and "copy constructor" mean.

Comment: Moreover, a constructor which accepts arguments is **not** something you can call _"default constructor"_

Comment: In your example, you are using the copy constructor of `std::shared_ptr` not the copy constructor of `Init`. But anyway, your "copy constructor" is not a copy constructor (a copy constructor takes a `const Init &)` as argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy constructing a shared pointer calls the copy constructor of the shared pointer. This `std::shared_ptr<Init> b(a);` is not constructing an `Init`. Instead it constructs a `shared_ptr` that shares ownership with `a` of the same `Init` instance. In your code only a single `Init` instance is created. Sharing ownership of one instance is the purpose of having multiple copies of a shared pointer.

`Init(std::shared_ptr<Init> z)` is not a copy constructor. A copy constructor is `Init(const Init&)` (which is also not used in your code).

It isnt obvious what you actually wanted to do, however, this is how you can create a second `shared_ptr` that manages the lifetime of a second `Init`  instance which is copy constructed from the first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// better not using namespace std;

class Init {
private:
    int x;
public:
    Init(int y) : x(y){ // <--- use member initializer list for initialization
        std::cout << "default constructor called\n";
    }
    
    Init(const Init& other) : x(other.x) {   // <--- copy constructor
        std::cout << "copy constructor called\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    int k = 5;
    std::shared_ptr<Init> a = std::make_shared<Init>(k);
    std::shared_ptr<Init> b = std::make_shared<Init>(*a);
  
    // return 0; // not needed here
}
```

output:

```
default constructor called
copy constructor called
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ysdv6dvb5)

PS: `Init(int y)` is not a default constructor. A default constructor is one that can be called without arguments, eg `Int(int y=0)` would be a default constructor.